# Why I get this issue on DigitalOcean droplet, when deploy my project with docker-compose?

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, digital-ocean, droplet

I am building an application based on Django/DRF as backend and Angular as frontend. Angular is to be ran by Nginx. And I want to deploy this project on DigitalOcean's droplet using docker-compose. Here is the project's structure:

```
price_comparison_tool/
├── backend
│   ├── accounts
│   ├── api
│   ├── price_tool_project
│   ├── static
│   ├── staticfiles
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── entrypoint.sh
│   ├── manage.py
│   └── requirements.txt
├── frontend
│   ├── e2e
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── src
│   ├── angular.json
│   ├── CREDITS
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── karma.conf.js
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── nginx.conf
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── tsconfig.app.json
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   ├── tsconfig.spec.json
│   └── tslint.json
└── docker-compose.yml
```

Here is the content of `frontend` Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine as build

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build-prod

FROM nginx:1.17

COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And here what I have in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  api:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/code
  web:
    build: ./frontend
    volumes:
        - .:/frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - api
```

When I run `docker-compose up --build` locally on my machine (Ubuntu 20.04) -- everything  builds and runs OK -- I can see the project on url `0.0.0.0` and the API on `0.0.0.0:8000`. But when I do the same on DigitalOcean's droplet - I get following error:

```
Step 9/13 : FROM nginx:1.17
 ---> 9beeba249f3e
Step 10/13 : COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: COPY failed: stat usr/src/app/dist/: file does not exist
```

Can anybody point me what I am doing wrong? That's my first experience with Docker and Docker-compose, as well as with DigitalOcean...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally I could solve my problem by resizing my droplet from

`1CPU / 2 GB Memory / 50 GB Disk / FRA1 - Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) x64`

to

`2CPU / 4 GB Memory / 50 GB Disk / FRA1 - Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) x64`
.

After doing that the deployment went OK.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it:

- Build the docker image on my machine
- Upload it to their docker registry
- Pull the image from within the droplet and run it